# Find indices of rows from matrix A in matrix B

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

Let's consider two matrices A and B. A is a subset of B. How to find the index of each row of A in matrix B?
Here is a reproductible example:

```
set.seed(30)
B <- matrix(rnorm(n =30,mean = 0), ncol=3)
A <- subset(B, B[,1] > 1)
```

The goal is to find the indices `idx` which in this case gives row 4 and 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `apply` loops should do it.

```
apply(A, 1, function(a)
   which(apply(B, 1, function(b) all(b==a)))
 )

# [1] 4 5
```

Or alternatively, using  `colSums`

```
apply(A, 1, function(a) 
    which(colSums(t(B) == a) == ncol(B)))
# [1] 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
transform(A, idx = 1 * duplicated(rbind(A, B))[-seq_len(nrow(A))])
```

A nice solution without apply, originally by @Arun.

Answer (score 0):

```
> match(apply(A, 1, paste, collapse="\b"), apply(B, 1, paste, collapse="\b"))
[1] 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes a slightly different approach and relies on the fact that a matrix is a vector, it won't work if you have `data.frames`:

```
which( B %in% A , arr.ind=TRUE )[1:nrow(A)]
#[1] 4 5
```

And if you had really big matrices and wanted to be a bit more efficient you could use `%in%` on a subset like so:

```
which( B[1:nrow(B)] %in% A[1:nrow(A)] , arr.ind=TRUE )
```

But I don't expect this would make too much of a difference except in really big matrices.

If you had your data as `data.frames` you could do the same thing by passing just the first column to `which`:

```
A <- data.frame(A)
B <- data.frame(B)
which( B$X1 %in% A$X1 )
#[1] 4 5
```